# How do I handle new line characters in my sentences? - spacy NER

Tags: python, spacy

I'm trying to train spacy NER, and I collected all my sentences, but many have embedded new line characters '\n'  so when I enter the train data into my jupyter notebook, it failed with an error

> ```
>                  TRAIN_DATA = [('Who is 
>                                        ^
> SyntaxError: EOL when scanning string literal
> ```

What should I do with these?

Data looks like this (

```
TRAIN_DATA = [('Who is 
Shaka Khan?', {'entities': [(7, 17, 'PERSON')]}),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Jupyter**

If the problem is in jupyter you need to have 3x **'** around strings that are on several lines like this

```
string=""" This string has many lines
            that continues here
            and here """
```

In your case that would be

```
TRAIN_DATA = [('''Who is 
      Shaka Khan?''', {'entities': [(7, 17, 'PERSON')]})
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you've copy pasted the data, which is why this can happen. You could simply resolve the issue within Jupyter by just deleting the newline. Alternatively I would suggest that you import data to Jupyter not using copy paste.

**Remove newline character**

If you want to remove the newlines within string there are many options. Here is one

```
import re
string = re.sub('\n', '', string)
```

**Explanation**

1. Line: import of regex modul
2. Line: Use method 'sub' that
   substitutes first input '\n' with '' in string.

   out:
   ' This string has many lines    that continues here    and here '

Im guessing that you might be using pandas, so to do this on a column you can do the following:

```
df[col_name]=df[col_name].str.replace(r'^\n','')
```

Comment: The original text contains the newline characters. I can easily remove them, but if I do so I would have to replace it with another character of equivalent length probably whitespace in order to maintain the start and end index of the entity. Will removing the original newline have any impact on the model generated?  Also I generated the train data from a c# program, I may have to tweak it a bit to output the triple quote if I go that route.

Comment: It think it depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you are trying to analyze sentences I would suggest replacing newline characters with white space. Unless the newline carry a meaning - then replace it with a end-of-sentence-character that can be used when you are tokenizing the sentence.
It is my guess that removing the newline character will not have impact on the generated model at this. However, you can easily test it afterwards.